# opening file in python on mac stored on a shared folder

Tags: python, macos, raspberry-pi

I'm sharing a folder on a raspberry pi that has a text file I want to open in python on my mac (MacOS Sierra).

I've setup a share on the pi a long time ago which I can access from Finder on my Mac.  So in otherwords I can manually open the file on my Mac so its not an access issue.

The raspberry pi's name is: raspberrypi-two

my line of code is:

```
f = open("//raspberrypi-two/Home Directory/newcode/1-config/sensorID.txt","r")
```

but I get an Errno 2 File or directory not found:

I've found lots of examples on openning files in different folders but not so much for files on other computers and not sure if opening a file on on a linux computer from a mac makes it any more special...

thank you in advance....

Comment: use the absolute path of your shared folder on Mac if you run the script on your mac

Comment: Duh...I feel dumb now...thank you

Comment: you don't need the double slash at the beginning of your path, use one slash instead